# Using panels and\or contexts to build simple blog w/ static menu

Tags: views, panels, nodes

My goal is to build a simple blog that has a vertical list containing a library of blog titles and then the "meat" of a selected bog entry on the left.  I want the library list to be static such that it is always there whenever the user selects different blog articles.

This seems to me to be somewhat simple but for the life of me, it's got me stumped.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want a right sidebar with a menu containing links that you've manually added? First create the menu, then add links, then assign the layout positioning via blocks/regions or pages/panels.

Comment: @murraybiscuit: Thx but I think I've got most of that done.  The part I can't figure out is how to have the right sidebar appear on each article page using panels and not blocks.  Maybe it isn't possible but wanted to try nonetheless...

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to do:

- set up your panel as normal - include the 'block' of information you want visible in the section you want it
- click on the settings icon and select Visibility: Add new rule:

[image]

This allows you to set the conditions under which that particular block of information will be visible. You can have it appear only on nodes of a particular type for example.